# How to change database in django in runtime

Tags: python, database, django, authentication

I have in my User Profile, one field to define the Database name, that user can connect.

Like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    dbname = models.CharField(u'Database name', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

How can I set - in runtime - django to use the database name pre-configured in my UserProfile?

Thanks

Comment: `request.user.DBNAME`? I'm not sure if I understood the question.

Comment: I will try to explain better.. I have in my User Profile one field named DBNAME... each user will connect to a different database... I have many models.. when I get my view, I get the DBNAME from user profile and get the data from that database... but I don`t know if is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Django you define mutiple databases like this in your settings.py file

```
DATABASES = {
    'app_data': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'postgres_user',
        'PASSWORD': 's3krit'
    },
    'DBNAME_1': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}
```

Now consider app_data is where you store all your user and you want user=User_1 and then connect to User_1's database.  use the `using()` function to select your database connection by name

```
>>> user = Auth.objects.using('app_data').get(user=user)
>>> print user.database
DBNAME_0
>>>Data = SomeTable.objects.using(user.database).all()
```

Read more on how to use multiple databases in Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)

Comment: Ok, but where I use the using() function? In these example.. I have "app_data" with contains all my users, and for each database I create a DBNAME in my DATABASES ?

Comment: IF DBName are names of different databases which you expect to connect to, then each of them needs to be defined in the settings.py file

Comment: Ok, I understand that.. but I try to put Auth.object... in my settings but doesn`t work.. where I put these code?

Comment: Auth.objects would be an example of one model

Comment: keep the first db as your default database where you search for the user details... and the other databases u store your data